# Javascript regex to check if a value begins with a number followed by anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i go about doing a regex to see if it begins with a number and any character can follow after. My current expression is

```
var validaddress = /^[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
```

But this isn't the right way. Im new to this, help anyone?

Comment: Works okay for me, what's the problem?

`/^[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test('5anything'); // true`

Comment: Can you give an example of when it doesn't work the way you want?

Comment: Your regex looks correct. Please post more of your code and the input you expect to match the pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need character(s) after the digit, try this:

```
var validaddress = /^[0-9].+$/;
```

If characters after the digit are optional, use this:

```
var validaddress = /^[0-9].*$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is: `var validaddress = /^\d.*$/;`

`\d` - Matches any digit
`.*` - Matches any character except newline zero or more times.
Or replace `.*` with `.+`, if you are looking for at least 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^[0-9]/` as the regular expression.

If it only needs to start with a number, I'd only check that...

Comment: `.*` means "zero or more" which translates to your digit not necessarily being followed by anything.

Answer (score 0):

when you say "any character follow" -- do you mean any alphanumeric character or just anything (i.e. including space, comma, slash etc)?
if it is the latter, how about this:

```
var validaddress = /^[0-9].+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should work

```
/^\d+.+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the $.  Also, a '.' would suffice for "any character".  This one works for me:

```
var validaddress = ^[0-9].+;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `/^\d/` as the briefest approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string of these values and you want to find each individually try this:

```
(^|(?<=\W))(\d\w*)
```

You can then do a loop through each match.

[Regexr example](http://regexr.com?2tpfk)